# PacketTunnelProvider network extension not called Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, networking, vpn

I am trying to add a PacketTunnerProvider network extension to my project. The method startTunnelWithOptions(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: (NSError?) -> Void) Never gets called

However, I am able to succesfully establish a VPN connection using the network extensions bundle id for the providerBundleIdentifier

This is my code used to establish a connection

```
let vpnManager = NETunnelProviderManager.shared()

 func initVPNTunnelProviderManager() {

    let config = NETunnelProviderProtocol()

    config.providerBundleIdentifier = self.tunnelBundleId
    config.providerConfiguration = ["lol": 1]
    config.serverAddress = self.serverAddress
    config.username = self.username
    config.passwordReference = passwordRef

    vpnManager.loadFromPreferences {
        (error: Error?) in

        self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = vpnProtocol
        self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "Connect_1.0.0"
        self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true

        self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences {
            (error: Error?) in
            do {
                try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my PacketTunnel entitlements file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.vpn.api</key>
    <array>
        <string>allow-vpn</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.touchcore.Connectionapp</string>
    </array>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)touchcore.Connectionapp.PacketTunnel</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension</key>
    <array>
        <string>packet-tunnel-provider</string>
        <string>app-proxy-provider</string>
        <string>content-filter-provider</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>`
```

Answer (score 4):

> The method startTunnelWithOptions(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: (NSError?) -> Void) Never gets called
>
> However, I am able to succesfully establish a VPN connection using the network extensions bundle id for the providerBundleIdentifier

What exactly do you mean it never gets called? If you're able to successfully establish a connection then `startTunnelWithOptions` is being called.

If you're trying to determine that it' being called by using an `NSLog()`, keep in mind that that will only show in the debug log if you attatch the debugger to the provider instead of your container application.

**This will be difficult as the provider is initialized and the `startTunnelWithOptions` function is called before you get a chance to attach the debugger.**

A useful work around in this situation is to sleep in order to give the debugger time to attach.

```
- (void) startTunnelWithOptions:(NSDictionary *) options
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *)) completionHandler
{
    
    // Give debugger time to attach, 10 seconds is usually enough
    // Comment this out before you release the app or else you 
    // will be stuck with a 10 second delay on all connections.
    sleep(10); 

    // Continue with execution
    . . .
}
```

Then, when you initialize your PacketTunnelProvider it will wait 10 seconds before fully entering your logic inside of the `startTunnelWithOptions` function.

So, during this time in XCode you can go to `Debug->Attach To Process->YourVPNProviderProcess` and wait for it to fully initialize.

[image: Attach the debugger to a running process]

Comment: Hey nathan i have a network extension but it can call from my main app. please give me some suggestion or explain me why it can't called. Thanks.

Comment: as per this answer here you said it take 10 seconds to execute but in my case that is never called.