# Network Extension didn't called

Tags: ios, swift, networkextension

I am trying to connect VPN using `OpenVPNAdapter` but the `PacketTunnelProvider` isn't called from the controller. What am i missing here?

**Controller.swift**

```
import NetworkExtension

var providerManager: NETunnelProviderManager!
var provider = PacketTunnelProvider()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadProviderManager {
        self.configureVPN(response: self.arrResponse[0], serverAddress: self.arrResponse[0].iP, username: "vpn", password: "vpn")
    }
}

func loadProviderManager(completion:@escaping () -> Void) {
    NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { (managers, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.providerManager = managers?.first ?? NETunnelProviderManager()
            completion()
        }
    }
}

func configureVPN(response:Response,serverAddress: String, username: String, password: String) {
    
    let data = Data(base64Encoded:response.openVPNConfigDataBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    print(data!)
    let decodedString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(decodedString)
    self.providerManager?.loadFromPreferences { error in
        if error == nil {
            let tunnelProtocol = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
            tunnelProtocol.username = username
            tunnelProtocol.serverAddress = serverAddress
            tunnelProtocol.providerBundleIdentifier = "***.*****.********.***********.********"
            tunnelProtocol.providerConfiguration = ["ovpn": data!, "username": username, "password": password]
            tunnelProtocol.disconnectOnSleep = false
            self.providerManager.protocolConfiguration = tunnelProtocol
            self.providerManager.localizedDescription = "SMVPN"
            self.providerManager.isEnabled = true
            self.providerManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error == nil  {
                    self.providerManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                        if error == nil {
                            self.provider.startTunnel(options: nil) { error in //this  called here not in network extension
                                if error != nil {
                                    print(error!)
                                }else {
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            print(error!.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Project Entitlement

[image]

**PacketTunnelProvider.swift**

```
import NetworkExtension
import OpenVPNAdapter

class PacketTunnelProvider: NEPacketTunnelProvider {
    
    var startHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)?
    var stopHandler: (() -> Void)?
    var vpnReachability = OpenVPNReachability()

    var configuration: OpenVPNConfiguration!
    var properties: OpenVPNConfigurationEvaluation!
    var UDPSession: NWUDPSession!
    var TCPConnection: NWTCPConnection!

    lazy var vpnAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter = {
        let adapter = OpenVPNAdapter()
        adapter.delegate = self
        return adapter
    }()

    override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        // Add code here to start the process of connecting the tunnel.
        guard
            let protocolConfiguration = protocolConfiguration as? NETunnelProviderProtocol,
            let providerConfiguration = protocolConfiguration.providerConfiguration
            else {
                fatalError()
        }
        guard let ovpnFileContent: Data = providerConfiguration["ovpn"] as? Data else { return }
            let configuration = OpenVPNConfiguration()
            configuration.fileContent = ovpnFileContent
            do {
                properties = try vpnAdapter.apply(configuration: configuration)
            } catch {
                completionHandler(error)
                return
            }
        configuration.tunPersist = true

        if !properties.autologin {
            if let username: String = providerConfiguration["username"] as? String, let password: String = providerConfiguration["password"] as? String {
                let credentials = OpenVPNCredentials()
                credentials.username = username
                credentials.password = password
                do {
                    try vpnAdapter.provide(credentials: credentials)
                } catch {
                    completionHandler(error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        vpnReachability.startTracking { [weak self] status in
            guard status != .notReachable else { return }
            self?.vpnAdapter.reconnect(afterTimeInterval: 5)
        }

        startHandler = completionHandler
        vpnAdapter.connect(using: self)
    }
    
    override func stopTunnel(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Add code here to start the process of stopping the tunnel.
        stopHandler = completionHandler
        if vpnReachability.isTracking {
            vpnReachability.stopTracking()
        }
        vpnAdapter.disconnect()
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func handleAppMessage(_ messageData: Data, completionHandler: ((Data?) -> Void)?) {
        // Add code here to handle the message.
        if let handler = completionHandler {
            handler(messageData)
        }
    }
    
    override func sleep(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Add code here to get ready to sleep.
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func wake() {
        // Add code here to wake up.
    }
}

extension PacketTunnelProvider: OpenVPNAdapterDelegate {
    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        setTunnelNetworkSettings(networkSettings) { (error) in
            completionHandler(error == nil ? self.packetFlow as? Error : nil)
        }
    }


    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings?, completionHandler: @escaping (OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow?) -> Void) {
        setTunnelNetworkSettings(networkSettings) { (error) in
            completionHandler(error == nil ? self.packetFlow : nil)
        }
    }

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleEvent event: OpenVPNAdapterEvent, message: String?) {
        switch event {
        case .connected:
            if reasserting {
                reasserting = false
            }
            guard let startHandler = startHandler else { return }
            startHandler(nil)
            self.startHandler = nil
        case .disconnected:
            guard let stopHandler = stopHandler else { return }
            if vpnReachability.isTracking {
                vpnReachability.stopTracking()
            }
            stopHandler()
            self.stopHandler = nil
        case .reconnecting:
            reasserting = true
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleError error: Error) {
        guard let fatal = (error as NSError).userInfo[OpenVPNAdapterErrorFatalKey] as? Bool, fatal == true else {
            return
        }
        NSLog("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        NSLog("Connection Info: \(vpnAdapter.connectionInformation.debugDescription)")
        if vpnReachability.isTracking {
            vpnReachability.stopTracking()
        }

        if let startHandler = startHandler {
            startHandler(error)
            self.startHandler = nil
        } else {
            cancelTunnelWithError(error)
        }
    }

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleLogMessage logMessage: String) {
        NSLog("Log: \(logMessage)")
    }

}

extension PacketTunnelProvider: OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow {
    func readPackets(completionHandler: @escaping ([Data], [NSNumber]) -> Void) {
        packetFlow.readPackets(completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func writePackets(_ packets: [Data], withProtocols protocols: [NSNumber]) -> Bool {
        return packetFlow.writePackets(packets, withProtocols: protocols)
    }

}

extension NEPacketTunnelFlow: OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow {}
```

Extension Entitlement

[image]

> self.provider.startTunnel(options: nil) { error in // This is called here, not in network extension

This method is called from controller but didn't get called in network extension.

I posted all my code, so if I missed something, then please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

I found this question but I haven't figured it out yet.
[PacketTunnelProvider network extension not called Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701530/packettunnelprovider-network-extension-not-called-swift-3)

Comment: The code you posted might be useful for context, but I'm having a hard time pinpointing exactly what line you're having trouble with. It might be helpful to narrow the code you provided, or pinpoint which line isn't working like you expect.

Comment: @BRoyDawson i tried to call network extension with class object as i mention here `var provider = PacketTunnelProvider()` and trying to start tunnle with with this object in controller `self.provider.startTunnel(options: nil) { error in //this  called here not in network extension`. and than i shorted it out what i do wrong here. so, i posted a answer below please check it out.

Comment: @BRoyDawson simply i tried to tell is `self.provider.startTunnel(options: nil)` this method should called `networkextension` private tunnle but it will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found my mistake it's i tried to called network extension but it will never called. so i called `NETunnelProviderManager` directly and it will work.

```
self.providerManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                            if error == nil {
                                do {
                                    try self.providerManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()

                                } catch let error {
                                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                                }
                            }else {
                                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned anything about how you are testing network extension. You should attach a Network extension process before running your project for debugging. Then only network extension methods will trigger for debug.

Comment: means i need to attach debugger process. right?

Comment: First click on  debug -> attach a process by name, enter your extension name. Check in debug navigator whether process is waiting to be connected. If its waiting, then you run your main project

Comment: okay i will try it and let you know. thanks.

Comment: i can't find my app name there.

Comment: You need first run your app for it to show up in that menu

Comment: still don't get success.

Comment: Lets say you have NetDemoApp is your main app and NetExt is your network extension. Then you click on debug -> attach a process by name, enter NetExt and click Attach. This should start a process waiting to be attached in debug navigator. Then run your main application NetDemoApp.